# add new event to button

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Button a = new Button();
        a.Width = 100;
        a.Height = 100;
        a.Text = "one";
        a.Click += new EventHandler(test);
        form1.Controls.Add(a);        
}

protected void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Width = 100;
    b.Height = 100;
    b.Text = "two";
    b.Click += new EventHandler(test2);
    form1.Controls.Add(b );
    Response.Write("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}


protected void test2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
}
```

when click on `one` show Button `two` but when click on `two`button does not run `test2`???? 
when click on `two` page refresh.

i want first click on 'one' and then 'two'
show the button only after button a has been clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button a = new Button();
    a.Width = 100;
    a.Height = 100;
    a.Text = "one";
    a.Click += new EventHandler(test);
    form1.Controls.Add(a);

    Button b = new Button();
    b.Visible = false;
    b.Width = 100;
    b.Height = 100;
    b.Text = "two";
    b.Click += new EventHandler(test2);
    form1.Controls.Add(b);
}

protected void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    b.Visible = true;
    Response.Write("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}


protected void test2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
}
```

Comment: this is true but this way a roob

Answer (score 2):

You have to recreate dynamic controls (such as your new button `b`) and associate their event handlers *again on each postback*. Thus, you need to move the code from `test` to `Page_Load`. If you want to show the button only after button `a` has been clicked, either make button `b` invisible (simple  solution) or store some Boolean in the viewstate that triggers creation of `b` (more complicated solution).

Answer (score 1):

Each time an ASP page is accessed (or refreshed), the object is recreated and the Page_Load event is run. This means that when you hit the first button, the second is created and the event is subscribed to *in that instance of the page object*.

When you hit the button the next time, a new page object is created and in that page object the event has never been subscribed to.

Creating controls dynamically is often a bad idea, instead create all controls and hide those that you don't want to display right away. Also you should add a check for `IsPostBack` in your page load, so that you can differentiate between first-time initialization and when the object is recreated on postback.